# How do staff users edit their profiles in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-profiles

I'm new to Django. I'm working on a website that will only contain users as staff users. I'm the administrator. My plan is to register a user and give him his username and password to login; I want him **only** to be able to edit his profile to add more information, not to change existing attributes. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would probably be to create a appropriate ModelForm and a corresponding view, that checks that the instance the user want's to update is the own instance.

I you want to integrate this directly in the admin backend, you can also do this. The most djangoish way would propably be to create a own `ModelAdmin` class for the `User` that has the right methods overridden (see the methods starting[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods)). I think you should start with overriding `has_change_permission` where you can check if the object the user tries to edit, is his own and return False otherwise.

To replace the standard User ModelAdmin you need to do a little fiddeling in the admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # add the code here

# deregister the standard AdminModel and register the own one
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

(I'm using this code on a live site and it works create)